# MIDI Linux Gadget Module (g_midi) with iPad on Raspberry Pi

Tags: usb, dmesg, midi

I'm trying to use the MIDI Linux Gadget Module (g_midi) to turn a Raspberry Pi Zero into a USB MIDI device. I've enabled g_midi using the following commands:

```
echo "dtoverlay=dwc2" | sudo tee -a /boot/config.txt
echo "dwc2" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
echo "g_midi" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
reboot
```

And now a MIDI device appears in the list when I run `sudo amidi -l`.

When I connect the Pi Zero to a computer over USB, the computer detects a new MIDI device, and I can send MIDI messages between the Pi and the computer. I can plug and unplug the device as many times as I want, and the computer always re-recognises the Pi.

However, this is not the same using an iPad. When I plug the Pi data USB cable into the Camera Connection Kit (with the Pi Zero also being plugged in with the PWR usb), I can plug the Camera Connection Kit into the iPad, and it will recognise the Pi as a MIDI device. However, if I unplug and replug the Camera Connection Kit, the iPad fails to recognise the Pi again.

Plugging the Pi USB back into a computer causes the Pi to be recognised again on that computer, but not on the iPad. If I unplug the Pi and power it up again, I can get it to recognise fine again, but only the first time I plug it in.

I had a look using `dmesg -wH` and the output is as follows:

**Pi Zero being plugged initially into computer:**

```
[May27 11:58] dwc2 20980000.usb: new device is high-speed
[  +0.012000] dwc2 20980000.usb: new address 25
[  +0.008198] MIDI Gadget gadget: high-speed config #1: MIDI Gadget
```

**Pi Zero being plugged back into computer:**

```
[May27 11:59] dwc2 20980000.usb: new device is high-speed
[  +0.010505] dwc2 20980000.usb: new address 26
[  +0.006452] MIDI Gadget gadget: high-speed config #1: MIDI Gadget
```

---

**Pi Zero being plugged initially into iPad:**

```
[ +23.850688] dwc2 20980000.usb: new device is low-speed
[  +0.158771] dwc2 20980000.usb: new device is high-speed
[  +0.015806] dwc2 20980000.usb: new address 1
[  +0.007635] MIDI Gadget gadget: high-speed config #1: MIDI Gadget
```

**Pi Zero being plugged back into iPad:**

```
[  +5.517874] dwc2 20980000.usb: new device is low-speed
```

---

I have (very occasionally) managed to get the Pi Zero to be recognised a second time on the iPad by unplugging and replugging many many times, whilst waiting between replugs. I've timed when I unplugged and replugged, but these times are not reproducible. What I noticed on the rare occasion that the Pi Zero was recognised for a second time was that the message from `dmesg -wH` was:

```
[May27 11:52] dwc2 20980000.usb: new device is low-speed
[  +0.158547] dwc2 20980000.usb: new device is high-speed
[  +0.015820] dwc2 20980000.usb: new address 1
[  +0.008327] MIDI Gadget gadget: high-speed config #1: MIDI Gadget
```

and the strange part was that the `new address` was still 1, whereas on the computer the address incremented by one every time I plugged the Pi Zero in.

Not knowing anything about MIDI, USB or the Linux Gadget Modules, I'm not sure if this is significant, but as far as I can tell it's the only differing thing between when I get the Pi Zero to recognise on a computer compared to an iPad.

---

Has anyone had any experience with working with the MIDI Linux Gadget Module and an iPad, that knows what's wrong here? I would appreciate any help I can get with this.

Comment: Apparently, the `dwc2` driver does not completely reinitialize the port when un-/replugging. This looks like a bug that should be reported. Try reloading the `dwc2` module.

Comment: @CL. I tried running
    `modprobe -r dwc2`,
    `modprobe dwc2`,
    `modprobe -r g_midi`,
    `modprobe g_midi`,
after I had unplugged the Pi Zero for the first time, but the next time you plug it in it still does not recognise and shows the
    `dwc2 20980000.usb: new device is low-speed`
in `dmesg -wH`

Answer (score 1):

This could be because by default the g_midi gadget (which is deprecated BTW) uses 250mV VBus Draw, which means that it expects the host device to send 250mV to the device. I don't know if the iPad does that.

This is not a bug on g_midi because it is a generic configuration. You can change this when compiling the kernel by changing the `CONFIG_USB_GADGET_VBUS_DRAW flag` to a `mV * 2`, as specified by the USB spec.

Example, to require 13mV only:

```
CONFIG_USB_GADGET_VBUS_DRAW=26
```

Also, try to use the latest Linux kernel version available to you, it might this bug fixed.